# Rails & simple_form // No route matches [PATCH] "/spots.10"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, crud, simple-form, simple-form-for

An error raise when i try to update the model. `spot`

> No route matches [PATCH] "/spots.7"

i use Rails 6, bootstrap and the gem `simple_form`

i've created manualy the `config/routes.rb` and the form is comon to `new.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb`

routes

```
  index GET    /spots(.:format)               spots#index
    new GET    /spots/new(.:format)           spots#new
  spots POST   /spots(.:format)               spots#create
   edit GET    /spots/show/:id/edit(.:format) spots#edit
 update PATCH  /spots/:id(.:format)           spots#update
   show GET    /spots/show/:id(.:format)      spots#show
 delete DELETE /spots/:id(.:format)           spots#destroy
```

Controller

```
class SpotsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_spot, only: [:show, :destroy, :edit, :update]

  def index
    @spots = Spot.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @spot = Spot.new
  end

  def create
    @spot = Spot.new(spot_params)
    @spot.save
    redirect_to index_path
    
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    @spot.update(spot_params)
    redirect_to index_path
    
  end

  def destroy
    @spot.destroy

    redirect_to index_path
  end


  private

  def spot_params
    params.require(:spot).permit(:name, etc...)
  end

  def set_spot
    @spot = Spot.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

view - `edit.html.erb`

```
<div class="container">

    <h1>FORM</h1>

    <%= render "form", spot: @spot %>

</div>
```

the partial `_form`

```
#HERE, i think, it come from this underline, the url passed as argument is bad 
    <%= simple_form_for (spot), url:(spot.new_record? ? spots_path : spots_path(spot)) do |f| %> 
      <%= f.input :name %>
             .
             .
             .

      <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
```

i've tried multiples things.
[Simple_form_for action hitting wrong URL on edit in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54051759/simple-form-for-action-hitting-wrong-url-on-edit-in-rails)

[Path helpers generate paths with dots instead of slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674116/path-helpers-generate-paths-with-dots-instead-of-slashes)

[Rails creating malformed routes with dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033853/rails-creating-malformed-routes-with-dots)

the singularisation `spot_path(spot)`  give me an error too.

i think, i'm close but i can't see my error!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in your path helper:
`spots_path` is generating the route to `spots#index` so `"/spots"`. If you give an argument to it like so: `spots_path(spot)` all the path helper method can do is append it to the path, therefore it generates `"/spots.10"`.

If you're generating the 7 CRUD (create, read, update, destroy) routes in Rails, you should use `resources :spots` in `routes.rb` and not do it manually. This will also generate the right prefixes for the path helper which you can find when you use the command `rails routes` in your terminal.

On top of that: The routes you created are not entirely correct, `show` is just  `spots/:id` for example (same for edit). But I guess this didn't work (it's because if you create the routes manually, the show route needs to be defined above the new route or it will confuse it with new).

As for the form, you do not need to create the url by hand, Rails' form helpers take care of generating the right route depending if the record is new or not, so just `<%= simple_form_for (spot) do |f| %>` will suffice.

Comment: OK, thanks for your quick feedback! i was thinking that you can adapt the path to any custom prefixes.  i will redo my route with `resources :spots `

Comment: You could, but `resources` provides everything you need. No need to reinvent the wheel and it mich easier to understand for other developers :)